# Expectation of exponential of a sum of two Wiener processes

Tags: expectation, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

Given volatility $\sigma_1$, $\sigma_2$ and time $t_1$, $t_2$, how to calculate the expectation $E(e^{\sigma_1 W_{t_1} + \sigma_2 W_{t_2}})$ where $W_{t}$'s are Wiener processes?

I am starting from the probability density function of normal distribution and calculating the integral, but get stuck a little in the correlation of Wiener processes. Thanks.

Comment: Suppose that $t_1<t_2$. Write $W_{t_2} = (W_{t_2}-W_{t_1})+W_{t_1}$ and use the independence of $W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}$ and $W_{t_1}$ to split up the expectation. After that you will have to use the stationarity of the increments and the fact that $W_r \sim N(0,r)$ for any $r>0$.

Comment: @saz It is truly great. Let me follow this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inspired by [saz's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2812674/expectation-of-exponential-of-a-sum-of-two-wiener-processes?noredirect=1#comment5799702_2812674), I am answering this question myself.

Assume $t_2 > t_1$, and notice $W_{t_2}-W_{t_1}\sim N(0, t_2 - t_1)$.

$E(e^{\sigma_1 W_{t_1} + \sigma_2 W_{t_2}}) = E(e^{(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)W_{t_1} + \sigma_2 (W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})}) = E(e^{(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)W_{t_1}})E(e^{\sigma_2(W_{t_2} - W_{t_1})}) = e^{\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_1 + \sigma_2)^2 t_1}e^{\frac{1}{2}\sigma_2^2(t_2-t_1)}$.

That $E(e^X) = e^{\mu+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2}$ where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ is used above.

Similarly the solution of the case where $t_1 < t_2$ can be derived.